# How to (base64) encode a protobuf as a String for REST

Tags: c#, rest, base64, protocol-buffers

I want to use **Protobuf** objects in **REST** service.

- I need to deserialize incoming string from base64 to a Protobuf object (IMessage)
- I need to serialize outgoing Protobuf object to base64 string

  What is the simplest way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**

Serialize:

```
using Google.Protobuf; // don't forget: .ToByteString() is an extension method
string encoded = proto.ToByteString().ToBase64();
// Output: ChAKDEdsb2JhbCBzdGF0ZRAB
```

Deserialize:

```
MyProtobufClass myC = new MyProtobufClass();
myC .MergeFrom(ByteString.FromBase64(messageBase64));
```

**Full version: helper class**

```
public static class ProtobufHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Transform base64 string message to protobuf IMessage object
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="messageBase64"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T DeserializeProtobuf<T>(string messageBase64) where T: IMessage, new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageBase64))
        {
            if (messageBase64.StartsWith("\"") && && messageBase64.Length > 2)
                messageBase64 = messageBase64.Substring(1, messageBase64.Length - 2);
            result.MergeFrom(ByteString.FromBase64(messageBase64));
        }
        return (result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Transform protobuf IMessage object to base64 string message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string SerializeProtobuf(IMessage message)
    {
        return (message.ToByteString().ToBase64());
    }
}
```

**Usage in REST service**

```
  public class MyCustomController : ApiController
  {

        /// <summary>
        /// REST Get method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="requestPayload">String containing a base64 serialized MyProtobufRequest object</param>
        /// <returns>String containing a base64 serialized MyProtobufReply object</returns>
        public string Get(string requestPayload)
        {
            var requestObj = ProtobufHelper.DeserializeProtobuf<MyProtobufRequest>(requestPayload);
            return (ProtobufHelper.SerializeProtobuf(GetHandler(requestObj)));
        }

        private MyProtobufReply GetHandler(MyProtobufRequestrequest request)
        {
           // Type your code here
           return new MyProtobufReply();
        }                
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion is totally wrong to use proto messages serialized into string and vice versa. It is exactly the contrary of the protobuf design.

The ideal solution is to set the content type into octet-stream (binary) and use the `toByteArray()` and the `parseFrom({bytearray})` methods to achieve the maximum performance. In this way your data will have a very small footprint on the wire and you will get a better network performance.

On the other hand the better solution could be to use streaming everywhere and stream the proto bytes with the method `protoObj.writeDelimitedTo({an http output stream})` and with `{protoDefClass}.parseDelimitedFrom({an http input stream})`